# Error Installing react-rails with Rails 5 beta.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-rails

Running a newly installed Rails 5 beta 3 with Ruby 2.2.3. Added [react-rails 1.6.0](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) in the gem file then bundle install.

Installed then `rails s`. Then error:

> Users/sylar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bundler/gems/rails-442207387e62/railties/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method`assets' for # (NoMethodError)

Is this a react-rails issue or rails 5 itself? Works ok in Rails 4.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if rails 5 --api has `require "sprockets/railtie"` commented out. Uncommented and all is well. This was found in `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 0):

This was not an option when you posted your question, but if you didn't manage to get react-rails working (and for anyone else with the same problem)...I was seeing the same error, but was able to fix it with the following steps:

1. Update Rails 5 beta 3 to the release version, and include react-rails in the Gemfile:

   ```
   gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'
   gem 'react-rails' # use whatever version you want here.
   ```
2. Run these terminal commands in the project root line:

   ```
   bundle install
   rails g react:install
   ```

At this point, a new error appeared when running rails s - then once I'd fixed that, a browser error showed up. I was able to fix everything with a few additional steps:

3. Add the following to app/assets/javascripts/application.js. If you are using require_tree ., ensure you place it before this line:

   ```
   //= require react
   //= require react_ujs
   //= require components
   //= require_tree .
   ```
4. Create app/assets/javascripts/components/components.js.
5. Add this line to config/assets.rb:

   ```
   Rails.application.config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/javascripts/components"
   ```

At this point I had react-rails working.

Hopefully that helps.